# Order posts saved as "featured" by specific number in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, customization

I have created a function for saving posts as "featured" and showing them on the homepage. It works with a custom checkbox in the admin panel. I did the function with help on forums but I would like to add to this function the ability to set a specific order number to every featured post and show them at the front page in this order. (choosing which one is the first, which is the second, third, etc…)

```
// FEATURED POST FUNCTION

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_checkbox_featured');

function add_checkbox_featured() {
add_meta_box('is_featured', 'Featured', 'print_checkbox_featured', 'post', 'side');}

function print_checkbox_featured() {
global $post;
$checked = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured', true) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
echo '<label for="checkbox_is_featured">Show at the front page <input id="checkbox_is_featured" name="is_featured" type="checkbox" value="1" '.$checked.'/</label>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_checkbox_featured');

function save_checkbox_featured($post_id){
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return $post_id;

   if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;

   if ($_POST['is_featured']){
            add_post_meta($post_id, '_featured', '1');
    }else{
            delete_post_meta($post_id, '_featured');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Add another `add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_order_featured');` and save the order in post_meta

Comment: yes, but how is the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for adding order for the featured post but on home page you have to use `meta_query` to display posts by entered order

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_checkbox_featured');
//add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_checkbox_featured_order');

function add_checkbox_featured() {
add_meta_box('is_featured', 'Featured', 'print_checkbox_featured', 'post', 'side');
}

/*function add_checkbox_featured_order() {
add_meta_box('is_featured_order', 'Featured Order', 'print_checkbox_featured_order', 'post', 'side');
}

function print_checkbox_featured_order() {
global $post;

}*/


function print_checkbox_featured() {
global $post;
$checked = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured', true) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
echo '<label for="checkbox_is_featured">Show at the front page <input id="checkbox_is_featured" name="is_featured" type="checkbox" value="1" '.$checked.'/></label>';

$forder = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured_order', true);
echo '<label for="checkbox_is_featured_order">Enter featured order
<input id="checkbox_is_featured_order" name="is_featured_order" type="text" value="'.$forder.'"/></label>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_checkbox_featured');

function save_checkbox_featured($post_id){
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return $post_id;

   if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;

   if ($_POST['is_featured']){
            add_post_meta($post_id, '_featured', '1');
    }else{
            delete_post_meta($post_id, '_featured');
    }

   if ($_POST['is_featured_order']){
            add_post_meta($post_id, '_featured_order', $_POST['is_featured_order']);
    }else{
            delete_post_meta($post_id, '_featured_order');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
i had this code for the home page 

    `query_posts('meta_key=_featured'); `

and now i tried with something like below but is not showing the post in the correct order.

    `query_posts(array('meta_query'=>'_featured_order', 'meta_key'=>'_featured'));  `

also I tried using only but is not working 
 
    `query_posts('meta_query=_featured_order');`

Comment: and last question, How I can show in the admin panel only one Meta box with the 2 checkboxes, Featured and Featured Order?

Thank you!

Comment: See my updated answer for showing both fields in same meta box , for order by google it http://wordpress.org/support/topic/meta_query-order-by-multiple-keys

Comment: Ok, the last question was something I thought and i tried but as i can't see the posts listed in the correct order I didn't know if it was working ok.
The orderby problem is something very confusing for me, i tried many things but… i think it's too hard for a non programmer like me. thanks anyway

Comment: @user2807090 Please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717408/wp-query-filter-by-multiple-meta-values-and-order-by-other-meta-values i guess this what you are looking for and my answer's concerned is to show how to add 2nd field in meta box not more than that so for order by can provide the links only